# View Information in Modal from MySQL/PHP generated table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, twitter-bootstrap

I thought this would be pretty simple however i'm unable to get this to work.
I haven't attempted any java/ajax as im not to good with that.

What i have is a table generated from this query

Im trying to have it so that when you click on the list-alt glyphicon it brings up a modal with the notes column in it.

```
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM data WHERE user='$loggedon' ORDER BY date DESC
```

The Columns for the database  order number[num] date[date] and notes[notes]
table:

```
    <script src='models/sorttable.js' type='text/javascript'> </script>
    <table class='sortable table table-hover table-bordered table-condensed table-striped' id='tables' border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Order Number</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>View Notes | Delete</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $id = $row['date'];
    $num = $row['num'];
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['num'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .fdate($row['date'], 'D F j, Y g:i A') . "</td>";
    echo "<td><a href='#?$num' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#notesModal'><span          class='glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt'></span></a>&nbsp|&nbsp<a href ='deltt.php?tt_date=$id'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

Second query to get notes

```
    $notequery=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT notes FROM data WHERE order='$num'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($notequery))
{
$ref = $row['notes'];
}
```

Modal

```
    echo "
<div class='modal fade' id='notesModal' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='mySmallModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>
<div class='modal-dialog modal-sm'>
    <div class='modal-content'>notes:$ref</div>
</div>
</div>";
```

I can see what the issue with this is, that $num always becomes the last entry in the table due to the loop. this is what i started with but i just cant figure my way around it i'm sure its quite simple

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to call the modal (as the title says), just call it from Javascript.

```
$("#notesModal").modal('show');
```

By clicking...

```
<a href="#" onclick="function(){ $('#notesModal').modal('show'); }"> Click me </a>
```